# How to Build Map on Website

Tags: web, dictionary, openlayers

I Want to build website which containt map on homepage like http://maps.burningsilicon.net/ . But i confuse how to build it and what tools which i should use.

Anyone can help me ? give me suggesstion please..

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps API: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html

Comment: may be i will use openlayers and use openstreetmap to get resource, but how to get spesific location to use as default index page ? I have get only all off the world.For Example i want to make map of Indonesia as default.

Comment: You need to get the latitude/longitude of a point in Indonesia. Since I'm being nice, you can use (-0.789275, 113.921327). This is what you would set your map centre to.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking out either Google Maps or Bing Maps.  They each have APIs available and thorough documentation for how to embed on a website.  They are also free to use.